# How to stop the execution of .sh script at certain time?

Tags: sh

I have the following script which ensure that a .php file will be invoked every 3 seconds.

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( i=0; i<43200; i++ ))
do

/usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/somefile.php


sleep 3
done
```

I would like to be able to stop the script excecution if the time is 23:58:59

Anyone can help me?

Thanks, Zoran

Answer (score 2):

```
case `date +%H%M` in 2359) break ;; esac
```

**Edit:** I discovered the zero padding in the date formatting string was not portable, so I took it out.  It's not useful or necessary in this case anyway.

Comment: Hi tripleee. Few questions...bracked closed, but not opened, why two ;; and what esac mean?

Comment: Read a basic intro to shell programming, find the `case` keyword. Yes, the syntax might look a little alien if you are new at this.

Comment: Hi I now have the following script, which does not stop the execution...[code]#!/bin/bash
case 'date +%0H%0M' in 1044) break ;; esac

for (( i=0; i<43200; i++ ))
do

/usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/http://www.mysite.com/httpdocs/myfile.php


sleep 3
done[code]                                                                and script doesnt seem to stop...continue to invoke the php file. What I am doing wrong? Any help?

Comment: No, you add the break condition inside the loop, and make sure you copy/paste the backticks correctly.  Those are reverse ticks (ASCII 96) not regular apostrophes. `for xxx; do case \`date +%H%M\` in ... esac; php; sleep; done`

Answer (score 1):

AGAIN me.

since your script has no imput youmcan try to launch yor script in the following way:

```
./yourscript.sh & sleep 10 && kill %1 && fg
```

give it a try.

Se

Comment: It is working for me

Answer (score -2):

I think there is no direct way without using a scripting language like python or perl.

here if yo want there is te perl script already implemented:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/shell-scripting-run-command-under-alarmclock/

---

Utilization summary:

Create a file installTimeout.sh containing the following:

```
wget http://pilcrow.madison.wi.us/sw/doalarm-0.1.7.tgz
tar -zxvf doalarm-0.1.7.tg
cd doalarm-0.1.7
make
```

and run the command:

```
source installTimeout.sh
```

now it's transparent to you.
When you want to give a timeout to your script yo just have to run:

```
doalarm 20 your script
```

Best,
Ste

Comment: Thanks Ste, but all that code look like Greek to me. I have no idea to achieve my goal.

Comment: ok... i try to make a summary at least u may be ale to use it.

Comment: He wants you to install a separate utility which kills your script after a particular amount of time.  This is hardly necessary; you can run a `cron` job to just kill the other script at the specified time, but that is something of a brute-force approach.  Also if you don't know when you start your script, how do you know how long you should make the timeout?  Yes, it's possible to calculate the time offset, but this is getting out of hand.